# How to add a listener to the requestcycle onbegin request?

Tags: listener, wicket-1.6

We are trying to get the server name, session id browser info... to keep the information in the MDC for logging.

For this we are trying to add a listener in the `RequestCycle` of the `onBeginRequest()` of `IRequestCycleListener`.
I have added a class  as follows:

```
public class RequestRListener implements IRequestCycleListener
{
  @Override
  public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle)
  {
      //TODO 
  } 
}
```

Now where to add the listener to get the above mentioned informations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class that extends `WebApplication` or `AuthenticatedWebApplication` in the `init()` function.

You need to get the request cycle listeners and add your new listener to the list.

So, if you want to output the requested URI you'd do something like this:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add( 
new AbstractRequestCycleListener()
{       
    public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle) 
    {                   
        if( cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest() instanceof HttpServletRequest )
        {
            HttpServletRequest containerRequest = 
                (HttpServletRequest)cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest();
            System.out.println("URI="+containerRequest.getRequestURI() );
        }
    };
}
);
```

Getting the browser info can be done almost anywhere, not necessarily just in the request.

```
String userAgent = WebSession.get().getClientInfo().getUserAgent();
```